# Why has defined? a state

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongomapper

I encounter a really strange problem in my sinatra app. The important code part is this one:

```
puts "url: #{url.inspect}"

is_music_post = nil
is_video_post = nil

is_music_post = defined?(url.music_post_id) != nil
is_video_post = defined?(url.video_post_id) != nil

puts "vid post: #{is_video_post}"
puts "music post: #{is_music_post}"
```

The URL objects are from mongo mapper. They look like this:

**obejct 1**

`#<Url _id: BSON::ObjectId('5345d525dcdda73224000240'), music_post_id: BSON::ObjectId('5345d51fdcdda7322400023d'), nice: "beat-rooftop", post_id: nil>`

Here it work as expected it return:

```
vid post: false
music post: true
```

**obejct 2**

`#<Url _id: BSON::ObjectId('5345d2f6dcdda732240001d8'), nice: "my-tale-boney-m-steppenwolf", post_id: nil, video_post_id: BSON::ObjectId('5345d2f6dcdda732240001d7')>`

Here it become strange, I expected true for vid post and false for music post, but I get:

```
vid post: true
music post: true
```

**obejct 3**

`#<Url _id: BSON::ObjectId('5345d525dcdda73224000240'), music_post_id: BSON::ObjectId('5345d51fdcdda7322400023d'), nice: "beat-rooftop", post_id: nil>`

And her is the same both values are true

```
vid post: true
music post: true
```

**WFT**

So my guess is that somewhere something hold a state of this. So how could I force it to reevaluate it every time?

**my system**

ruby -v ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]

**Update**

I think [@iain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335847) could be right with the lazy loading explanation. If this is true how can I disable this for this case?

Comment: can you print what `defined?(url.music_post_id)` gives you, that would give you a hint to what is happening

Comment: When its true it return method and nil or nothing when it's false, nothing unexpected

Comment: if it is nothing unexpected then I don't understand the question

Comment: by nothing unexpected i mean they are corresponding with the true and false values

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, MongoMapper is creating attributes lazily and `defined?` isn't checking the *value* of the field but whether the *field* is defined, so you'll need to find a better test to meet your expected goal. [There is a discussion about adding lazy attributes from a while back on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongomapper/Go2sNl6J5YA/hOg-MPr6jN8J), though I don't know if it was ever implemented.

The first time you've created an object, it has a `music post`, so it gets a `true` but `vid post` doesn't. The second time you don't use the music post field but it was created with the last object anyway, so you get `true` `true`. Object 3 will get `true` `true` also because of this.

Try putting the second object first. If you get a `true` for `vid post` but false for `music post`, you'll know it's something about the way attributes are being defined.

Comment: I test your idea with changing the object order, and your right in this case it's true for vid post. But I still don't understand how exactly this can happen.